# TYPO3 8 normal page linkhandler hook

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

is there a possibilty to change the processing of the normal page (Seite) linkhandler?

[image]

e.g. i want to change the page anchors fron c-uid to title-of-contentelement (CK Editor).

i think of something similar to the new record linkhandler, a typolink userFunc.

i do not mean the typoLink_PostProc post-processing.

maybe someone has worked with this:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79121-ImplementHookInTypolinkForModificationOfPageParams.html